# How to find data with specific character in specific position of a string in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

##### dada in ES:

| f1 (string) | f2(string) | id (int) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | abcdef | 1 |
| perl | ed**f**adfe | 2 |
| perl | ae**f**asdf | 3 |
| perl | fedae | 4 |

I want to find `f2[2]='f'`, i.e. the data with id=2 and 3

how to find it efficiently?

the length of f2 is fixed, may be up to 336 characters.

my solution is :

```
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "f2": ".{2}f.*" 
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't think using regexp would be efficient, any better choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to benchmark different options to see which one fits your dataset and usage pattern the best. These would include:

- your regexp
- turning `"f2": "edfadfe"` into `"f2_1": "e", "f2_2": "d", ...` in your indexing pipeline
- turning `"f2": "edfadfe"` into `"f2_spaced": ["e", " d", "  f", ...]` in your indexing pipeline or a custom token filter

Both preprocessing options would be very fast on query time but slower on indexing time and will use a LOT of disk space.

Comment: thanks for your reply. For the third solution.
`"f2_spaced": ["e", " d", "  f", ...]`.  As to my knowledge, there is no order in array type of ES. How can I filter `f2_spaced[2]="f"`, could you show me the DSL?

Comment: `f2_spaced` would be `keyword` and you can just use `”term": "  f"` (with spaces). I assume your strings don't contain spaces; if they do use another symbol for padding.

Comment: got it! good idea! thanks a lot!